# Tensorflow's weights overwrite themselves every epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

Question: How can I save different weights for every epoch? for example `tf_weights_epoch_1.hd5`, `tf_weights_epoch_2.hd5`..

I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 and this callback:

```
checkpoint_path = "./weights/tf_weights_.hd5"

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1,
                                                 save_freq='epoch')
```

Shouldn't be like an easy way to achieve it? maybe somehow append the variable `checkpoint_path`?

something like `checkpoint_path = "./weights/tf_weights_{}.hd5".format(cur_epoch_number)` and create another callback function which increases this counter by one every end of epoch? But it seems that there should be something built in like `save_freq=epoch` which saves every epoch.. (but it overwrites the file instead of creating a new one)

**EDIT: I found an approach:**

> if filepath is `weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5`,: then the
>   model checkpoints will be saved with the epoch number and the
>   validation loss in the filename.

Hopefully this will work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doc, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint

> filepath  string, path to save the model file. filepath can contain
>   named formatting options, which will be filled the value of epoch and
>   keys in logs (passed in on_epoch_end). For example: if filepath is
>   weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5, then the model checkpoints
>   will be saved with the epoch number and the validation loss in the
>   filename.